# Navigation drawer backstack, how to get the actionbar title to change with fragment on back click

Tags: android-fragments, navigation, title, drawer, fragment-backstack

so i managed to get a stock navigation drawer to work and the action bar title to change with the fragments selected. I've also managed to get the backstack working easy peasy.

What i can't figure out how to do is get the action bar title to change back with the back click. google documentations says to add a onBackStackChangedListener:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
        new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                // Update your UI here.
            }
        });
```

but i'm at a lost where to place it? they say when i .commit to changes so i assumed it was placed after

```
if (id == R.id.nav_spatial_awareness) {
            setTitle("Spatial Awareness");
            SpatialAwareness spatialAwarenessFragment = new SpatialAwareness();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager spatialAwarenessManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            spatialAwarenessManager.beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.main_content_layout, spatialAwarenessFragment, spatialAwarenessFragment.getTag())
                    .commit();
```

but that didn't work, this is what i tried and all i get is red squigglies

```
if (id == R.id.nav_spatial_awareness) {
            setTitle("Spatial Awareness");
            SpatialAwareness spatialAwarenessFragment = new SpatialAwareness();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager spatialAwarenessManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            spatialAwarenessManager.beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.main_content_layout, spatialAwarenessFragment, spatialAwarenessFragment.getTag())
                    .commit();

            getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                        public void onBackStackChanged() {
                            setTitle("Spatial Awareness");
                        }
                    });
```

please help me noob

so i tried this

```
if (id == R.id.nav_spatial_awareness) {
            setTitle("Spatial Awareness");
            final SpatialAwareness spatialAwarenessFragment = new SpatialAwareness();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager spatialAwarenessManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            spatialAwarenessManager.beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.main_content_layout, spatialAwarenessFragment, "spatialAwarenessFragmentTag")
                    .commit();

            getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                        public void onBackStackChanged() {
                            android.app.Fragment currentBackStackFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("spatialAwarenessFragmentTag");
                            if(currentBackStackFragment instanceof SpatialAwareness){
                                setTitle("Spatial");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

i gave my fragment a tag and then tried matching the instance and then changing the title, still no good :(

Comment: In your backstackchanged you can check which fragment is currently showing, and according to that you can change title of your toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal#back-fragments) is to add a `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` to your activity's FragmentManager.

Here is an example from a project I worked on:
(I have a navigation drawer with 7 Fragments and the OverviewFragment is the initial one that opens when the MainActivity opens)

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // open the default fragment
            OverviewFragment fragment = new OverviewFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_overview);
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_overview:
                fragment = new OverviewFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_schedule:
                fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_all_tasks:
                fragment = new AllTasksFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_announcements:
                fragment = new AnnouncementFragment();
                    break;
            case R.id.nav_my_courses:
                fragment = new MyCoursesFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_map:
                fragment = new MapFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new OverviewFragment();
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment currentFragment = 
        fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (currentFragment instanceof  OverviewFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_overview);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_overview).setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof ScheduleFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_schedule);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_schedule).setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof AllTasksFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_all_tasks);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_all_tasks).setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof MyCoursesFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_my_courses);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_my_courses).setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof AnnouncementFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_announcements);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_announcements).setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof MapFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_map);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_map).setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof SettingsFragment) {
            setTitle(R.string.title_fragment_settings);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_settings).setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the entire project: https://github.com/FCI-E-campus/fci-e-campus-android